# The lock instance cannot be shared between two .py files

Tags: python, multithreading, python-import

Recently I have been touching the multithreading area with python. The following example will better illustrate my question:
So I have two .py files, one is test.py and another is test2.py

in test.py:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread, Lock

lock = Lock()

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s')

def foo1():
    while True:
        with lock:
            logging.info(datetime.now())
            time.sleep(0.2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from test2 import foo2
    Thread(target=foo1).start()
    Thread(target=foo2).start()
```

in test2.py:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from test import logging, lock

def foo2():
    while True:
        with lock:
            logging.info( datetime.now() )
            time.sleep(5)
```

output:

```
2017-03-17 17:11:06,210 Thread-1 root.foo1 [INFO]: 2017-03-17 17:11:06.210000
2017-03-17 17:11:06,210 Thread-2 root.foo2 [INFO]: 2017-03-17 17:11:06.210000
2017-03-17 17:11:06,415 Thread-1 root.foo1 [INFO]: 2017-03-17 17:11:06.416000
2017-03-17 17:11:06,619 Thread-1 root.foo1 [INFO]: 2017-03-17 17:11:06.620000
```

So, the lock seems to have no effect. I tested if I put foo1 and foo2 in the same .py file, it will work.

Could anyone tell me why?

And I know this might involve some elementary knowledge that how python handles import, please forgive me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the really confusing parts of Python's import system. You don't have two modules, `test` and `test2`. You have three modules, `__main__`, `test`, and `test2`. Similarly, you don't have one lock, `test.lock`. **You have two locks, `__main__.lock` and `test.lock`.**

When you run `python test.py`, Python starts executing `test.py` as the `__main__` module, not the `test` module. When `__main__` imports `test2` and `test2` imports `test`, Python starts running `test.py` **again**, this time as the `test` module. Everything not inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` gets run again, including `lock = Lock()`, making a second lock.

In `__main__`, the two functions you set your threads to run are `__main__.foo1` and `test2.foo2`. `__main__.foo1` is using `__main__.lock`, while `test2.foo2` is using the `test.lock` it imported from `test`. Since these are different locks, there is no mutual exclusion.

---

Not directly related to your problem, but don't call your modules `test`, because there's already a standard library module by that name, and don't use circular imports. Having `test` import `test2` and `test2` import `test` will lead to all sorts of nasty bugs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. This is truly a part of python that I have noticed before but never dug into it, as it wasn't creating problems. I will try to test it, and then accept your answer. And thanks for the comment relating to test. Haha, I just felt it was a natural name for testing out some code. If I may ask, what names do you use, when you are tesing some codes.

Comment: @qichao_he: If it's just some quick experiment I'm going to throw away in 5 minutes, I frequently pick something like `asdf.py` or `foo.py`. If I'm going to work on it longer, I try to pick something descriptive, like `import_lock_test.py`.

Comment: @qichao_he So what is the solution to use a lock among 2 different modules?!

Comment: @RamtinMousavi: Restructure your program to remove the circular import.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Is there anyway to share a lock between two modules?